# returning only exact match in an api

Tags: python

I am trying to pull data from the government's new college scorecard website using the api.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
school=['boston%20college','harvard%20university']
for item in school:
    url='https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?school.name='+item+'&api_key='+key
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    response2 = response.read()
    json_data=json.loads(response2)
    #print json_data
    for series in json_data['results']:
        unitid=str(series['ope6_id'])
        lines=unitid+"/n"
        output=open('api_test.txt','a')
        output.write(lines)
        output.close()
```

My problem is, writing boston college this way will return all of the ids for any school that has the words boston and college in their name. Is their a way to only return the line if the name matches boston college exactly?

Comment: You'll have to read [the documentation](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/) -- all APIs are not created the same.

Comment: Looking [here](https://github.com/18F/open-data-maker/blob/api-docs/API.md#word-and-substring-matches-on-autocomplete-fields), there may not be an option for this. I would loop through the API results and validate the `school.name` value before writing to your file.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Sam. Would you be able to share an example of a way to validate this value before writing to the file?

Comment: Something like `if series['school.name'] in school:`...that won't exactly work because `'boston%20college' != 'Boston College'`, but it should get you started.